# How to connect slot with mutable argument to signal with const argument

Tags: c++, qt, constants, signals-slots

I need to connect [binaryMessageReceived](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#binaryMessageReceived) signal of QWebSocket to my slot which modifies the QByteData

The QByteData may be large so it might be really costly to copy it again in mutable variable each time. I want to reuse the existing QByteData

when I try to compile with following slot

```
void route(QByteArray& msg);
```

I get compilation error

```
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:255:9: error: static assertion failed: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible.
  255 |         Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X((QtPrivate::CheckCompatibleArguments<typename SignalType::Arguments, typename SlotType::Arguments>::value),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:255:9: note: ‘(((int)QtPrivate::CheckCompatibleArguments<QtPrivate::List<const QByteArray&>, QtPrivate::List<QByteArray&> >::value) != 0)’ evaluates to false
```

but if I change the slot to

```
void route(const QByteArray& msg);
```

it compiles just fine

I'm connecting slot like this:-

```
connect(this, &QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived, this, &WSManager::route);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that.

The signal argument is not meant to be modified if passed as `const &`. You are not even sure of the lifetime of the binary data in the emitter object (QWebSocket).

The *QByteData* is emitted from here : https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebsockets/src/websockets/qwebsocketdataprocessor.cpp.html#181
Nested in multiple classes hidden from the API, it's very dangerous to rely on this kind of attribute/data.

---

[`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details) uses the **implicit-sharing** Qt mecanism which avoid deep copy.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html

That means you can pass the object around without concern about the performances. And if at some point you need to modify it, you might end up working on the only actual instance of the data thanks to the move operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could connect to lambda and use const_cast inside the lambda function:

```
connect(this, &QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived, this, [this](const QByteArray &message) {
    this->route(const_cast<QByteArray &>(message));
});
```

Update: even you can cast constness away this way it doesn't mean it's a good idea to do that :) As it was pointed out in the other answer no data copying is done for unchanged QByteArray because of Qt implicit sharing mechanism.

Comment: Given that `QWebSocket` calls it back with a `const` reference and not a mutable one, I'd expect this to be extremely unsafe to do, which makes this a likely source of undefined behavior. Do we have any formal guarantees that mutating the `QByteArray` is safe to do (e.g. `QWebSocket` doesn't care for the data after the call), and that the `QByteArray` object passed through the slot is not actually `const` on the other side? If we don't have those guarantees, then this `const_cast` is not safe.

Comment: I agree with @Human-Compiler. I concentrated in "how" only but didn't point out if it is wise or not. Updated my answer with comment and upvoted ymoreau's answer.